# How to resolve IIS certificate Error?

Tags: iis

Recently there was a new deployment to my website. In web server, on click of browse website option in IIS using localhost, website is working fine but with a certificate error in the browser.

**Problem :** When trying to access the URL from client browser, I'm getting 503 communication error! What might be reason?

Need a quick resolution as the site is down :(

Comment: The Certificate error you receive when browsing localhost is because the Cert is for the website domain and not localhost or the site IP.  The Certificate error is generated by the Web Browser, not your server.  The 503 Error is an error generated by your server.

Comment: MyItchyChin - When its working fine in IIS local host, what could be the problem with client machine while trying to access the URL?

Comment: No, 503 is an error generated by the server.  Do you have a Proxy or something else at play in your environment?

Answer (score 0):

Enabled Directory Browsing in IIS & problem is resolved!